# How to use ordinal number suffix of loop in the jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add suffix number of loop index to my selector but it does not work. 
How could I do?

```
<script>
    for(var i=1; i<10; i++) {
        $(function() {
            $("#MyDialog" + i).dialog({......
```

I want to use `$("#Mydialog1") $("#Mydialog2") $("#Mydialog3") $("#Mydialog4") .... $("#Mydialog10")`

Comment: The problem is the use of a closure variable

Comment: Can you please elaborate. It is not clear

Comment: I want to use $("#Mydialog1")  $("#Mydialog2") $("#Mydialog3")  $("#Mydialog4")  .... $("#Mydialog10")

Comment: what is the error?